# I am trying to solve a problem where I encrypt a text and I am doing that fine, but I am getting the "(NULL)" too and I don't want that

Tags: c, cs50, c-strings, function-definition, caesar-cipher

This is the code of my program where I encrypt a text that the user gives me. this is for the CS50 course.

```
char* rotate(string plaintext, int k)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
  {
    if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
    {
      printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] - 65)+ k) %26 +65));
    }
    if (islower(plaintext[i]))
    {
      printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] - 97)+ k) %26 + 97));
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%c", (plaintext[i]));
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

That is all the program, I just want the NULL value to not appear at the end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Get rid of the magic numbers. Use `'A'` instead of `65`, `'a'` instead of `97`.

Comment: I think your function is supposed to return the encrypted string, not print it. You're getting `NULL` because of `return 0;`

Comment: Another problem: the second `if` should be `else if`. Otherwise your `else` will be run for uppercase characters, even though they were already processed by `if (isupper(...))`

Answer (score 2):

`return plaintext;` instead of 0 (NULL).

It is misleading that you call the argument `plaintext` when you mutate it into ciphertext.  Here is an alternative:

```
string rotate(string s, int k) {
    for(unsigned char *s2 = (unsigned char *) s; *s2; s2++) {
        if(!isalpha(*s2)) continue;
        *s2 = (toupper(*s2) - 'A' + k) % ('Z' - 'A' + 1) +
             (isupper(*s2) ? 'A' : 'a');
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: There would be some utility in allowing function to return `null` as long another bracketed section allowed for returning  `plaintext`.  eg, couldn't `null` be checked by caller for indication conversion did not occur?

Comment: @ryyker Yes, absolutely, for example of a memory allocation failed.  It's somewhat risky, though, as you pass in the variable that you return, this means if you want to handle the error you need to retain the original variable.  `realloc()` is an example of a function that is tricky because of that.

Comment: Note that `isalpha(*s)` is UB when `*s < 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica string (aka char *)  with char signed and  (*s & ~0x70)?

Comment: Shouldn't `s` be incremented at end of loop body, not at the start? Currently you are returning a pointer to the end of the string, not to the beginning, is that your intention?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Fixed.  I always learn something when you comment on my answers :-)

Comment: `is...()` functions are typically designed to handle -128 to 255 for the reason of code calling `is...(some_signed_or_unsigned_char)`.  It creates a minor hole with `is...(EOF)` and `is...(255)`.  IAC, best to treat `char`s as _unsigned_ in character handling to support `string.h`: "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)."

Comment: @AllanWind, you are still incrementing `s2` to early.

Comment: @HAL9000 Right.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are *printing* the encrypted text but are *not* returning it. Does the caller print it? I suspect it does because of your `(NULL)` statement.

1. You [probably] want to put back the encrypted chars into the string (i.e. remove the `printf` because caller will do it).
2. Change the function return to `plaintext`. When you did `return 0;`, this was the probable source of the `(NULL)` being printed.
3. Don't use decimal constants. Use `'A'` and `'a'`
4. Doing `i < strlen(plaintext)` will cause the operation to have O(n^2) time because `strlen` must rescan the string on each iteration.
5. Better to do: `plaintext[i] != 0` as this will run in O(n) time.

Here is a refactored version:

```
char *
rotate(string plaintext, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; plaintext[i] != 0; i++) {
        // get current plaintext char
        int chr = plaintext[i];

        if (isupper(chr))
            chr = (((chr - 'A') + k) % 26 + 'A');

        else if (islower(chr))
            chr = (((chr - 'a') + k) % 26 + 'a');

        // put back encrypted char
        plaintext[i] = chr;
    }

    return plaintext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function as is does not make a sense.

It should not output anything. Its task is to encrypt the source string or to create a new encrypted string based on the source string and return it.

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `65` and `97`.

And the name of the function `rotate` is confusing.

Apart from this either use the type `char *` for the parameter and the return type of the function or the typedef name `string`.

For example the function can look the following way

```
string encrypt( string plaintext, int k )
{
    for ( string p = plaintext; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p = 'A' + ( *p - 'A' + k ) % 26;
        }
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p = 'a' + ( *p - 'a' + k ) % 26;
        }
    }

    return plaintext;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef char *string;

string encript( string plaintext, int k )
{
    for ( string p = plaintext; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p = 'A' + ( *p - 'A' + k ) % 26;
        }
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p = 'a' + ( *p - 'a' + k ) % 26;
        }
    }

    return plaintext;
}

int main( void )
{
    char plaintext[] = "Hello, World!";

    puts( plaintext );
    puts( encript( plaintext, 4 ) );
    puts( encript( plaintext, 22 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello, World!
Lipps, Asvph!
Hello, World!
```

As your function initially was named as `rotate` and the value of the parameter `k` can be negative because the parameter has the signed type `int` then it seems that each alpha character after encryption must be again an alpha character. If so then the function can be defined the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef char *string;

string encript( string plaintext, int k )
{
    for ( string p = plaintext; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p = 'A' + ( *p - 'A' + k ) % 26;
            if ( *p < 'A' ) *p = 'Z' - ( 'A' - *p  - 1 );
        }
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p = 'a' + ( *p - 'a' + k ) % 26;
            if ( *p < 'a' ) *p = 'z' - ( 'a' - *p  - 1 );
        }
    }

    return plaintext;
}

int main( void )
{
    char plaintext[] = "Hello, World!";

    puts( plaintext );
    puts( encript( plaintext, 4 ) );
    puts( encript( plaintext, -4 ) );
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above

```
Hello, World!
Lipps, Asvph!
Hello, World!
```